# How to transform a LOB (Binary image) to send to Firebase Storage

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-oracledb

I need to return some Oracle images that are recorded in LOB field to send them to Firebase Storage.

I am using oracledb with typescript library to call a procedure that returns certain records. One of the fields is LOB (images). I need to return this data and send this image to Firebase storage. I can't code it.

```
import { IConnection } from "oracledb";
import oracledb = require("oracledb");
oracledb.fetchAsString = [ oracledb.CLOB ];

export async function uploadImages(db: IConnection) {
  const query = `
      BEGIN 
        mgglo.pck_wglo_binario.p_obter_binarios_filtro
        (
          retorno               => :retorno,
          pfiltro               => :pfiltro,
          pmod_in_codigo        => :pmod_in_codigo,
          pcodigoempreendimento => :pcodigoempreendimento,
          pcodigobloco          => :pcodigobloco,
          pcodigounidade        => :pcodigounidade
        );
      END;`;

  const bindvars = {
        retorno               : { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR },
        pfiltro               : 0,
        pmod_in_codigo        : 1,
        pcodigoempreendimento : 5689,
        pcodigobloco          : 9645,
        pcodigounidade        : 8966
  }

  const exec = await db.execute(query, bindvars);
  const row = await exec.outBinds["retorno"].getRow(); 
  console.log(row);

}
```

Return:

```
{ BIN_IN_CODIGO: 469,
  CAT_IN_CODIGO: 63,
  BIN_BO_ATIVO: 'S',
  BIN_ST_MIME: 'image/png',
  BIN_ST_NOME: 'Image 1.png',
  BIN_LO_BINARIO:
   Lob {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: null,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: { end: [Object], finish: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     iLob:
      ILob {
        valid: true,
        autoCloseLob: true,
        type: 2007,
        offset: 1,
        pieceSize: 8060,
        length: 814115,
        chunkSize: 8060 },
     close: [Function] },
  BIN_ST_DESCRICAO: 'Teste Valmir',
  BIN_DT_CRIACAO: 2019-05-28T13:32:37.000Z,
  BIN_BO_LINK: 'N' }



FIELD: BIN_LO_BINARIO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOB is coming out as a Lob instance. That can be used for streaming large objects, but if the LOB is relatively small (compared to the amount of memory the Node.js process has access to), then you can override the default to get and String or Buffer depending on whether the LOB is a BLOB or CLOB.

Here's an example that fetches a BLOB out as a Buffer from [this post](https://jsao.io/2019/06/uploading-and-downloading-files-buffering-in-node-js/#downloading-files):

```
const getSql =
 `select file_name "file_name",
    dbms_lob.getlength(blob_data) "file_length",
    content_type "content_type",
    blob_data "blob_data"
  from jsao_files
  where id = :id`;

async function get(id) {
  const binds = {
    id: id
  };
  const opts = {
    fetchInfo: {
      blob_data: {
        type: oracledb.BUFFER
      }
    }
  };

  const result = await database.simpleExecute(getSql, binds, opts);

  return result.rows;
}
```